# In django, how can I construct a method that gives the sum of subclasses

Tags: django, django-models

My problem is essentially this. I have a class (lets say runners) and a subclass (say with leaptimes or something, for different leaps). Now I want a variable in the class that is the total sum of leaptimes. Basically:

```
class Runner(model.Model):
     ....
     def total_time(self):
          return self.????.annotate(Sum('leap__time'))

class Leap(model.Model):
     runner = ForeignKey('Runner',...)
     time = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

The ??? is there to demonstrate that this is the kind of thing I want. Is it possible to achieve this along these lines, and is it then possible to define a new function within the class Runner which uses total_time?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you typically do not *annotate*, but *aggregate*. You can here use a `Sum` over the set of `Leap`s for a specific runner, like:

```
class Runner(model.Model):

     # ...
     def total_time(self):
          return self.leap_set.aggregate(total=Sum('time'))['total_time'] or 0
```

The `or 0` is used in case the set of `Leap`s is empty. In that case the aggregate will be `None`. By using `or 0`, we replace that by zero.

An alternative, without the `leap_set` (as related name), is by filtering the `Leap` objects:

```
class Runner(model.Model):

     # ...
     def total_time(self):
          return (Leap.objects.filter(runner=self)
                              .aggregate(total=Sum('time'))['total_time'] or 0)
```

In case you want to annotate an *entire queryset* of `Runner`s with their `total_time`, you can use `.annotate`:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Runner.objects.annotate(total_time=Coalesce(Sum('leap__time'), 0))
```

We here use the `Coalesce` function to use `0` instead of `None` in case the set of `Leap`s is empty.

Comment: ManyThanks, it clarifies a lot. And it almost works! I get a None from Leap (instead of empty). How can I modify to get 0 for that situation?

Comment: Can you specify what code part? Does the runner has any `Leap`s?

Comment: @anders: can you edit your question with some data, and the result you obtain (and want)? Right now it is a bit unclear what you want to get changed.

Comment: This is an alias for my real problem and you have given me the solution. The only problem was that when there are no leaps, I did not get an empy set but None, so 0 did not take effect. I guess I can fix that with an if-statement, but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: It definitely did! Thank you again!